# Why can't I find information about Magentio Extension in this site?

Tags: extensions

I am looking for extensions for my sites but I can't find any information here.

Comment: Welcome to Magento stackexchange.... Please describe which extension  are you needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/

This is Magnento market place.

You will find all registered extension here.